getting this error in my angular webApp: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first
I want to play notification sound in my angular website when receive message through socket. but getting this error- Audio play failed:  NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
Here is my code sample -
`export class SocketService {
    private isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(inject(PLATFORM_ID));
    private notification_sound!: HTMLAudioElement;
     
    constructor() {
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            this.notification_sound = new Audio('../../assets/sound/notification-souond-1.wav');
        }
        ...
    }

    socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
        if (this.notification_sound) {
            this.notification_sound.play().then(() => {
                console.log("Audio played");
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Audio play failed: ", err);
            });
        }
    });
}`

Please help...
I need it play automatically when message is received.

This is how browser works, you can show a popup requesting if sound can be enabled, so that the user has to interact with the page, also you get consent for playing the sound
